# How can I make ExtUtils::Manifest include empty directories?

Tags: perl

I am trying to build a Perl module for distribution. The directory structure looks like this:

```
demo
demo/files
demo/examples/example1.pl
demo/scripts
lib
```

I used this command to generate the MANIFEST file:

```
perl -e "use ExtUtils::Manifest qw(mkmanifest); mkmanifest();"
```

The file is created but all of the empty folders are ignored, so `demo/files` and `demo/scripts` are not in the MANIFEST.

How can I tell [`ExtUtils::Manifest`](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::Manifest) to include empty folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a zero byte file called `.exists` in the otherwise empty directories.

Comment: yes I was thinking about this but I checked many distributions that have empty folders without .exists. I tried this solution now and I see it includes the folder with the file like demo/files/.exists.